# How to write a SQL query for this case?

Tags: sql

I need to write an SQL query where I can compare the results with the Excel cube. For the particular table, it was updated for all contract numbers with only 5 digits where they added 0 in front of every five digit number. And they left remaining number i.e 6 digit numbers the same. But, this update is done in ETL package and the added 0 is transparent for me, ie I cannot see it in the table.

For example: for 90034 they added 0 in the beginning of the number i.e 090034 but in the ETL package it appears to be 90034 in the table where 0 in front of 90034 is transparent.

And in Excel cube all the numbers are 6 digit numbers ex., 090034

So, how can I write a SQL query to check if all the 5 digit numbers are been added with the 0 in the beginning and compare it with Excel cube?

Comment: What is the datatype of the column that holds the data in your database?

Comment: Your problem may be that you are storing string data in a numeric datatype which would strip off the leading zeros.

Comment: The column in table is a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a snippet that will add leading zeroes to numbers of six or fewer digits:

```
 select   right('000000' + convert(varchar(6), MyID), 6)
```

That assumes that your column is called `MyID` and that it's a numeric data type already.  If it's already a string, you can try this:

```
 select   right('000000' + ltrim(rtrim(MyID)), 6)
```

DISCLAIMER:  This was done from memory and not tested.

Comment: The column in the table is a string.

Answer (score 0):

Its better for comparison purposes if the data in the database is stored as a varchar or nvarchar since it is clearly NOT a number or it would not have leading zeros.

If however you can't fix that and know the number of total character the string should have, this method would help.

```
create table #test (myfield int)
insert into #test (myfield)
values(090034)
select * from #test
select Right('000000' + cast(myfield as varchar(6)) , 6) from #test
```